# Visual Studio - How to rename Elements

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a timer "timer1".

[image]

I already wrote code for the timer.

How can I rename the timer?
I tried to rename it over the properties:

[image]

However, if I change the functions name in `Form1.cs` according to the new Timer name (newName), then I get errors.

**Before:**

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

**After:**

```
private void newName_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

**Error:**

```
no definition for "timer1_Tick"
```

And this page appears if you open the file **Form1.cs**:

[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the timers properties and click on the lightning bolt:

[image]

Now you can change the functions name.
Credits to [@KSib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2524589/ksib) for pointing this out.

---

**Alternative Solution:**

Open the **Projectmap Explorer (Solution Explorer)**:

[image]

Open the file `<FORMNAME>.Designer.cs`

Search for errors:

[image]

You can see that the old name is still entered in here for some reason, maybe the developers forgot to implement the rename function properly. Change it to the new function name.

```
this.newName.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.newName_Tick);
```

It should work again!

Comment: I wouldn't encourage editing the designer file. Instead just have him click that lightning bolt in the properties window and change the event name there.

Comment: @KSib thank you for pointing this out, I improved the solution and credited you